# Fetch get canceled on async action server

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, fetch

I have a fetch request like

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/test`, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-cache',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(result => console.log('success'))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

And a nodejs express router (express-promise-router) for the request

```
this.router.get('/test', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  response.status(200).send({'status': 'ok'});
});
```

When the fetch gets called the success is logged. So that's good.
But when I change the nodejs router function to async like

```
this.router.get('/test', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  return asyncFunction().then(result => response.status(200).send({'status': 'ok'}));
});
```

The fetch gets canceled and the console log displays `TypeError: Failed to fetch`.

When I call the /test api with the browser URL or Postman I get a successful result.
I can't figure out why the fetch is failing. (Also tried it with Axios with the same result).

Comment: have you change the path from "/test" to "/login" ?

Comment: where are you calling fetch in asyncFunction

Comment: @ManjeetThakur No sorry, it's also "/test"

Comment: @YouBee asyncFunction is just an example. The router url is getting called by the fetch. Since the router is an express-promise-router their shouldn't be a problem Using Postman (or browser URL) gives a correct response.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong track with the fetch issue.
The issue wasn't related to the fetch but to the event in which the fetch is called.
At the end of the method I needed an event.preventDefault() so the event was stopped and the fetch was handled correctly.